# Using Bootstrap modal on JSP page

Tags: java, spring, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, bootstrap-modal

I have a users table with `Info`, `Edit` and `Delete` buttons for each row.

```
<tbody>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${not empty customers}">
        <c:forEach items="${customers}" var="customer">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${customer.id}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${customer.name}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${customer.phoneNumber}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${customer.email}"/></td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                    <form:form action="/customerDetails"><input type="hidden" name="email" value="${customer.email}"/>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></button>
                    </form:form>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                    <form:form action="/findCustomer"><input type="hidden" name="email" value="${customer.email}"/>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                    </form:form>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                    <form:form action="/deleteCustomer"><input type="hidden" name="email" value="${customer.email}"/>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                    </form:form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <h2>There is no registered customers</h2>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</tbody>
```

When I click on Delete button, that customer is deleted immediately without any conformation. I want to use Bootstrap modal for a confirmation with **Yes** and **No** options. You see that each `Delete` buttons surrounded with `<form:form action="/deleteCustomer"...>` tag. Is there any way to add Bootstrap confirmation modal while keeping this structure and not adding any Ajax call in my code?

Comment: In order to stop the execution flow while you are waiting for the input from the user, you have to change your logic. Bootstrap Modal will not stop the `action` to be performed until it gets input.

Comment: Which Bootstrap version you are using?

Comment: @VPK What can I do make this working with a minimum changes in my code?

Comment: Have a look into this example: https://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/f5mv9r6x/8/, you have to open the modal dialog onClick of button. Get the input from user and then perform the action you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use your approach, notice you are creating so many forms in the page when is not really needed. I suggest you to use AJAX to delete the elements and reload the table. The main changes would be something like this:

```
<tbody>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${not empty customers}">
        <c:forEach items="${customers}" var="customer">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${customer.id}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${customer.name}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${customer.phoneNumber}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${customer.email}"/></td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></button>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-customer-id="${customer.id}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <h2>There is no registered customers</h2>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</tbody>
```

In your JS file

```
$('table .btn-warning').click(showInfo);
$('table .btn-danger').click(removeRecord);
...

function removeRecord(){
    var customerId = $(this).data('customer-id');
    bootbox.confirm({
                message: "Sure to delete?",
                callback: function(result) {
                    if (result) {
                        $.ajax({
                            method: "POST",
                            url: getCtx() + "/yourRemoveURL",
                            success: function (jsonResponse) {
                                //your on success actions, maybe reload the table or remove the row

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id attribute in your delete button.

```
<td style="text-align: center">
                    <form:form action="/deleteCustomer"><input type="hidden" name="email" value="${customer.email}"/>
                        <button id="deleteBtn" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                    </form:form>
                </td>
```

Add javascript on your page:

```
$('#deleteBtn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form=$(this).closest('form');     
    $('#confirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
        .one('click', '#delete', function() {
            $form.trigger('submit'); // submit the form
        });
});
```